# Is there an XML-like language (or any language) which allows easy expression of overlapping data?

Tags: xml, set, overlap, venn-diagram, data-serialization

(This is PROBABLY in the wrong site but I am unsure of where the right site is to assign this question to. Mod(s), please forgive and assist me.)

I have the following sequence:

```
cdadbcdacdbcbc
```

I have the following example "code" attempt to tag the sequence:

```
<c>c<d>d<a>ad<b>bcda</a>cdb</d>cb</b>c</c>
```

Notice that is "bad XML". It gets a "start/end tag missmatch" error in XML Marker. I did that on purpose to demonstrate.

I was trying to, and desire to, efficiently "tag" elements of a sequence in a string.

I confess I'm having difficulty knowing how to express this question. Is there a language that allows me to easily (efficiently) express (possibly, wildly) overlapping sets (think of Venn Diagrams) "found" in a sequence like the one above? Thank you.

Comment: There is a vast literature on the subject of overlap markup. You could start with Jeni Tennison's article at http://www.jenitennison.com/2008/12/18/representing-overlap-in-xml.html and with the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_markup. But although the question is interesting, it's off-topic for SO, so I'm going to vote to close

Comment: May I ask where I should place it instead?

Comment: I would ask on the xml-dev mailing list. But it would be best to do some reading first.